# undefined control sequence \label

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to run the following script

```
\documentclass[•]{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \begin{center}
    \subfigure[Original image]{\label{fig:edge-a}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{1}}
    \subfigure[After Laplace edge detection]{\label{fig:edge-b}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{3}} \\
    \subfigure[After Sobel edge detection]{\label{fig:edge-c}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{2}}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Various edge detection algorithms}
  \label{fig:edge}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The basis for this script is [this link](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23267) where the author explains how to place several figures with local and global captions for each figure and the entire figure set, respectively. The only difference is that I am using my own images and my own preamble (the link does not offer one).

When I run it I get the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \label
>   {fig:edge-a}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{1}
>   ...ig:edge-a}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{1}}

Why does this occur? Isn't the \label control sequence independent from any usepackages? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is `\includegraphics`, not `\label`. You're missing `\usepackage{graphicx}` to use `\includegraphics` (The OP of the given link does have `\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}` however

Comment: Always show tex error messages in a code block not as a quotation, and preserve the original line endings, the messages change meaning if line breaks are changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \label {fig:edge-a}\includegraphics 
                                               [scale=0.75]{1}
l.7 ...fig:edge-a}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{1}}
```

which shows the undefined control sequence is `\includegraphics`. This is because you don't have

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

---

Beware that `subfigure` has been deprecated several years ago and its successor is `subfig`; the command `\subfigure` should be changed into `\subfloat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
    \subfloat[Original image]{\label{fig:edge-a}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{1}}
    \subfloat[After Laplace edge detection]{\label{fig:edge-b}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{3}} \\
    \subfloat[After Sobel edge detection]{\label{fig:edge-c}\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{2}}
  \caption{Various edge detection algorithms}
  \label{fig:edge}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use `\centering`, not the `center` environment.

Comment: That works but unfortunately the images are not appearing. they are jpegs of 565X605 dimension...

Comment: Oh I get it because of the `[demo]` option in `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. Nevermind your answer is correct thank you

Comment: @user32882 Sorry, I forgot to remove it.